# Google Protocol Buffers List of Lists Python

Tags: python, json, list, parsing, protocol-buffers

Hi I have a question concerend about protocol buffers for list of lists in json:

**Example .json (testjson)**

```
"outcome": {
    "col": [
        "datetime",
        "return"
    ],
    "val": [[1199232000000, -0.0066], [1199318400000, -0.0033]]
}
```

**My .proto File (cum_ret.proto)**

```
message CumReturn {
  
  message period_value {
    oneof types{
      int32 day = 1;
      float return = 2;
    }
  }
  message period_values {
    repeated period_value value = 1;
  }

  message outcome {
    repeated string col = 1;
    repeated period_value val = 2;
  }

  outcome outcome_returns = 2;
}
```

**I parse the json with the following code:**

```
testjson = {
    "outcome_returns": {
        "col": [
            "datetime",
            "cum_returns"
        ],
        "val": [[1199232000000, -0.0066705691], [1199318400000, -0.0033641154]]
    }
}
 
import cum_ret_pb2 as CumRet 
from google.protobuf.json_format import Parse
cumrets = Parse(json.dumps(test_json), CumRet.CumReturn())
```

**But I got the error msg:**

```
Failed to parse 1199232000000 field: expected string or bytes-like object...
```

---

**Could someone help**: getting a List of List of int and float into .proto schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to implementing a list of lists is to create a new message for your list:

```
message ListOfInt {
  repeated int32 value = 1;
}
```

and when you call this, use

```
  message outcome {
    repeated string col = 1;
    repeated ListOfInt val = 2;
  }
```

---

However, I think you have a different issue in your code.  Your "period_value" message expects either an int32 or a float.  The maximum int32 value is 2,147,483,647, but you are trying to fit 1,199,232,000,000 into that field.  Hence, the error message that the value cannot be parsed.  Try changing the int32 to an int64:

```
message period_value {
    oneof types {
      int64 day = 1;
      float return = 2;
    }
  }
```